# Area lights issue with GPU Metal

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, osx

I use Blender with a MacBook M1 Metal with Cycles. I have downlighters on ceiling to illuminate the scene. Each one has a point light and an area light to avoid dark shadows on top.

When I render the scene with CPU, area lights are rendered:

[image]

But not if I render it with GPU:

[image]

I've tried changing render devices in Preferences, also the *GPU Backend* from *Metal* to *OpenGL*, but problem persists. And I've faced this issue in several projects.

The problem is GPU renders almost two times faster than CPU, and I don't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: pls provide blend file, thx.

Comment: I don't know how to provide blend file here, sorry.

Comment: open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've provided .blend file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=9NERmZLK" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/9NERmZLK/)

Comment: In the blend file, I deleted all materials and elements, but lights have the same issue... so I don't know what could be wrong.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this? I don't know what could happen.